# Z-score in Python and R: differences in the results

Tags: r, python-2.7

I am applying the Z-score in Python and in R folk singing this [example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.zscore.html) with the same data set

## Python

```
from scipy import stats
a = np.array([ 0.7972,  0.0767,  0.4383,  0.7866,  0.8091,  0.1954,
                   0.6307, 0.6599,  0.1065,  0.0508])
stats.zscore(a)
array([ 1.1273, -1.247 , -0.0552,  1.0923,  1.1664, -0.8559,  0.5786,
        0.6748, -1.1488, -1.3324])
```

## R

```
a <- c(0.7972,  0.0767,  0.4383,  0.7866,  0.8091,  0.1954, 0.6307, 0.6599,  0.1065,  0.0508)
(a - mean(a))/sd(a)

 [1]  1.06939901 -1.18300390 -0.05258212  1.03626165  1.10660039 -0.81192795
 [7]  0.54889230  0.64017636 -1.08984414 -1.26397161
```

The results are different

Comment: As a blind guess, I wonder if python is dividing by the standard error of that sample; EDIT: just tested, that's not it

Comment: `stats.zscore(a, None, 1)`

Comment: yes using stats.zscore(a, None, 1) i get the same result of R. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, the param being set to one in the above comments specifies the degrees of freedom (`ddof`) in the call to [scipy.stats.zscore()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html).

Answer (score 3):

Python and R both evaluate the variance of your data in the function calls you've made. It seems that Python and R differ in their definition of variance. Python computes the biased estimator for sample variance while R uses the unbiased.

The difference comes down to a divisor of `N` versus `N-1` in the expression for variance, where `N` is the length of the data. This means Python will say the variance is `0.0920912` while R says it's `0.1023236`. See Wikipedia's page on [Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation) for a more detailed explanation.